# DateTime struct in C#. Why the DateTime is used as Type for Creating the Property "public DateTime Date { get; }". Why not anything else. like string

Tags: c#, datetime, struct

if I create a class or struct as Cat. Can i declare a property as

```
public Cat catname {get;}
```

as a Property, like in the `DateTime` struct it contains the Property

```
public DateTime Date { get; }
```

`DateTime` is used as a type in the same struct which is named as `DateTime`.

Basically all i want to clarify can we use the Class or struct name as Type in the Same class or Struct.

Comment: Yes you can declare a property that returns the containing type - have you tried it? If it does not work for you post a reproducible example.

Comment: e.g. `public struct Cat {public Cat catname {get;}}`. Obviously you would have to put some logic in the getter that would return a `Cat` (just like there is in `DateTime.Date`).

Comment: The classic example would be `class LinkedListNode<T> { public T Value { get; set; } public LinkedListNode<T> Next { get; set; } }`, which would be hard to write otherwise.

Comment: Returning a `string` would be a critical bug, like the ones that end up in the news. Only last week someone was arrested for accessing child pornography sites because police in Spain handled date strings in the US format (4/7)as if they were in the European (7/4)format, just because that poor guy got the same dynamic IP someone else used months ago

Comment: The `anything else` is the new [DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) type coming in .NET 6. The `Date` property can't change though because *every* .NET application depends on it returning a `DateTime`. Instead of adding a `DateOnly` or `ToDateOnly` to `DateTime`, [FromDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.fromdatetime?view=net-6.0) was added to the new struct

Answer (score 0):

To answer `Why not anything else, like string` the only possible alternative is the new [DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) type coming in .NET 6.

The `Date` property can't change though because *every* .NET application depends on it returning a `DateTime`. Instead of adding a `DateOnly` or `ToDateOnly` to `DateTime`, [FromDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.fromdatetime?view=net-6.0) was added to the new struct.

Returning a string would be a critical bug, like the ones that end up in the news. Like [this case](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html) where a family's parents was arrested for accessing child pornography sites because police in Spain handled date strings in the US format (`10/11/2016`) as if they were in the European (`11/10/2016`) format. The same dynamic IP was assigned by the IP to both customers on different dates, but the Spanish police misread the US alert and focused on the wrong customer.

[The Spanish family wrongly accused of child pornography due to a mistake reading a date](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html)

As for a method returning its parent type, it's very common eg in static factory methods. In`DateTime` itself, [static DateTime.FromBinary(long)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.frombinary?view=net-6.0) will take a `long` representing ticks and return the corresponding `DateTime`

Comment: Yay for `DateOnly`.  I can remember being in Redmond during the beta program back in 2000-ish and asking why there wasn't a `Date` type.  Storing dates in DateTimes causes all sorts of issues.  Yay again!!